# Do I need to connect "active low"?

Tags: sensor

Probably a simple question;
For [this](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/TCS34725.pdf) sensor, should I connect the interrupt pin 5 to ground?

The function of the pin is unclear to me. To add to the confusion page 3 says the pin is active low. Does keeping it low enable the chip to work? Or does the pin have another function and will keeping it low prevent the chip from working (like keeping a reset pin low)?

Comment: Active low is a logical thing. If the pin function is to reset the sensor, and it is an "active low" input then a low signal will cause the sensor to be reset. Sometimes active low signals will have an 'n' or 'l' appended to the end. E.g., "rst_n" or "rst_l". Sometimes they are shown with a bar on top.

Comment: I recommend that you add a pullup to the signal, and also connect it to your processor using a series resistor. That way you preserve all options.

Comment: Use a 10K pull-up resistor.  You may not need it, but when trouble-shooting, you can trigger on it going low to find possible problems with your sensor/logic/software.

Comment: "Active low" means "true when the voltage is low" (as opposed to the usual reverse). Is this pin an input or an output? (Note that on a chip I'm currently working with, the active-low ~RESET must be held *high* for the chip to work--it's "not resetting".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using the interrupt, then you can pull it high with a pullup resistor - this allows you to use the pin (if you choose too in the future). However, if not, then you can tie it to 0V.

The reason for the pin is that when you are doing a conversion, you have to wait. Rather than wait for the conversation to finish by polling the AVALID bit in the STATUS register, you can do something else or go to sleep.

The device will let you know when the conversion is done and you can access it.

Interrupts make the electronics more efficient because you can do more things than waiting around and polling.

Comment: The interrupt pin is an output from the sensor - if not used it may be left unconnected.  There would be no reason to Ground it.

Answer (score 4):

The interrupt is an output, hence the "O" on the datasheet. It is open-drain active low so connecting it to ground will not cause harm.

[image]

The purpose and function of the interrupt output is fully explained on page 9, and I don't see any purpose in repeating it here. It's intended to connect to an interrupt input on your microcontroller, with a pullup resistor to Vdd (since it's the drain of an n-channel MOSFET).

Answer (score 2):

The table "Terminal functions" on page 3 denotes pin 5 as

```
INT 5  | O | Interrupt — open drain (active low)
```

It is an OUTPUT, open Drain means it is the drain of a FET, you can imagine it as one terminal of a switch, where the other terminal is connected to GND. When this output is activated, the "switch" closes and connects this pin to GND. (i.e. when active, there's 0V)

If you don't need it, leave it unconnected. If you connect Vcc to it, you form a short circuit as soon as this output becomes active. Connecting the pin to GND is no problem.